# Open Multiple Excel Files using VBScript in Read and write mode

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have an Excel file named "ABCD.xlsm" in three different folders.

When I open these files using VBScript one after the other I cannot run the macros and the addin.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set theFile = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\Temp\Excellocation.txt", 1, False)

Do While theFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    retstring = retstring & theFile.ReadLine
Loop
theFile.Close
lx_loc = retstring
fso.DeleteFile "D:\Temp\Excellocation.txt"

set objExcel = Createobject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.visible = True
objExcel.workbooks.open(lx_loc)
msgBox "RUN macro CallVSTOMethod and press ok",1, true
```

In the code the text file has the location of the Excel file.

If there is only one use of this code, then I have no issues. When I call this function more than once, I can't run the addin or the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when you open your file with a connection, it is locking this file, so you cannot open it for that reason. What you can do, is copy past a duplicate and open the copy. It will open right away! ;)

Comment: i couldn't understand what u mean by "copy past a duplicate". Should i make a copy of the excel file and then open it?

Comment: This is it. Make a copy of the excel file and then open it ;)

Comment: let me try that. In the mean time can i know what difference does this make?? because none of the Excel files are related to one another, other than Same name

Comment: I do believe your macro create a connection to all of these files and when it starts it locks all the other one.